# Ajax post is returning error function on callback

Tags: php, ajax

I am posting data using ajax to a page named **working.php**, data is being stored in database means everything is working fine but on the callback error function is thrown.

Here is the script:

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#testimonial_add').click(function(){
            var nm=$('#name').val();
            var message=$('#msg').val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'working.php',
                data:{name:nm, msg:message},
                success: function(html){
                    alert(html);
                },
                 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                  alert(errorThrown);
              }                 
            });
        });     
    });
</script>
```

Working.php page

```
<?php
    include('../function.php'); 

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['msg'];
    if($name == null || $message == null){
        echo 'All fields are required';
    }
    else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO testimonials(testimonial_name,testimonial_text) VALUES ('".$name."','".$message."')";
        dml($query);
        echo 'Data has been inserted';
    }
?>
```

In error function on alert **textstatus is error** and **errorThorwn is empty alert box**

Also can i give php function name in url of ajax

Here is the Dml function being called

```
function dml($query){
    $db=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','entrepreneurshipdp')
    or die('not connected');
    mysqli_query($db,$query); 
    mysqli_close($db);
}
```

Comment: Can you please have the alert(); in the error:  function get the textStatus parameter?

Comment: Also, I don't know what dml() is in the PHP file, but are you completely sure that it doesn't throw an error after running the query?

Comment: textStatus parameter is showing error in alert.
I don't think that error is being thrown as I am getting record in my database

Comment: Don't let the frameworks guess your data type, set them explicitly so it's not prone to errors. If you want responses as html then use `dataType: 'html'` in jquery and `header('Content-type: text/html')` in php.

Comment: okay, then please let me know the status code of the response, I was hoping sg like this would appear in that parameter. Oh and an error from let's say post insert validation, or anything can definitely throw an error after insert

Comment: that didn't change the climax but have specified the dataType @slash197

Comment: status code is 0

Comment: that is impossible. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @LászlóStahorszki no it is possible...

Comment: I learned sg new today. :O Last thing to the OP: please don't forget mysql_real_escape_string() before building the SQL Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things cause status=0

1. Running on file protocol
2. Ajax request is cancelled by navigation event

In your case, I doubt it is one. So it leaves the page navigating away. In your case what you are clicking is most likely submitting the form. Since you are not cancelling the default action of the click, the form is submitting and the killing the Ajax request off. So stop the default action from happening.

```
$('#testimonial_add').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
});
```

Or if you are using a submit button, change it to be a regular button and it will no longer submit the form.

Comment: Can I mention function name in URL like working.php/function name